predefined link in php post to mysql database
I am posting data to my mysql database the data is youtube channel link and channel name, what I am doing here in the code below is post the whole youtube link, I want to add this link https://youtube.com/channel/ pre entered in the form and the user has just to add the channel id and then it posted in the db as one link like this https://youtube.com/channel/channelId
        <form id="channelForm" class="mb-4">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="channelName" placeholder="channel name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="channelURL" placeholder="channel id" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">add channel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

php save code
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root"; // replace with your MySQL username
$password = ""; // replace with your MySQL password
$dbname = "youtube_channels_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO channels (name, url) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $url);

// Set parameters and execute
$name = $_POST['name'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$stmt->execute();

echo "New channel added successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>


Why not just get the user to enter the channel ID in the form, and your PHP code can prepend the URL to it before it puts it into the database? Or maybe actually store the root URL separately in the database (since it's the same for all channels, why store it repeatedly?), and then just prepend it to the channel ID at the point where you actually need to (e.g. if you're displaying it or making a link or something). Then if you just store channel IDs alone in the database you can search through them, sort them, etc if needed. Just a thought.

@ADyson yes this is what I want to achieve

OK. That isn't quite what you asked for in your post, but i think it's a better design and I'm glad you agree. So what's stopping you from doing it exactly?
